# Trying to add data attribute value to an input on a different page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a call to action button with a data-title attribute that holds the page title, when I click this link I basically want to be taken to the contact page (new page) and populate the subject input field with this title but I seem to having problems. Can anyone advise?

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){

enquiryCTA = $j('#enquiry-cta');

   enquiryCTA.on('click', function(){
      var dataTitle = $j(this).data('title');
      $j('span.your-subject').find('input[type=text]').val(dataTitle);
    });

});
```

HTML (on post page)

```
<a href="http://localhost/jmccplantsales/contact-us/" id="enquiry-cta" class="right enquire-cta" data-title="HGV1300 dci">Make Enquiry</a>
```

HTML (on contact.php page)

```
<form action="/jmccplantsales/contact-us/#wpcf7-f118-p4-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="118">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="3.1.1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f118-p4-o1">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="5ac1807bbb">
</div>
<p>Your Name (required)<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><br>
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" size="40"></span> </p>
<p>Your Email (required)<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-email"><br>
<input type="text" name="your-email" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email" size="40"></span> </p>
<p>Subject<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-subject"><br>
<input type="text" name="your-subject" value="" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text" size="40"></span> </p>
<p>Your Message<br>
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-message"><textarea name="your-message" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-textarea" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea></span> </p>
<input type="submit" value="Send" class="wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-submit"><img class="ajax-loader" src="http://localhost/jmccplantsales/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="visibility: hidden; ">
<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't without with passing it in the URL as part of the query string or with a cookie.

Comment: hi, sorry Im not completely sure what you mean and how could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because your javascript function only executes on the page containing the button; it doesn't carry on executing on the new page with the contact form. So you never reach the line that changes the value of the subject field.

If you have a number of these buttons on the same page, each with a different subject, you could just add the subject to the URL of each one in the HTML e.g.

```
<a href="http://localhost/jmccplantsales/contact-us/?subject=HGV1300%20dci" class="right enquire-cta">Make Enquiry</a>

<a href="http://localhost/jmccplantsales/contact-us/?subject=something_else" class="right enquire-cta">Make Enquiry</a>
```

However, from your example, it looks like you might only have one of these links on a page. I assume the data-title attribute is dynamically set by some other piece of javascript? If so, you could update your javascript function to get the link href and the add the subject parameter to it:

```
enquiryCTA.on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // Stop the link from clicking through
  var dataTitle = $j(this).data('title');
  var url = $j(this).attr('href') + '?subject=' + dataTitle; // get existing link href and add the subject to it
  window.location = url; // load this new url instead of the one in the link href
});
```

Whichever of these two methods you use, you will then need to write some PHP to populate the subject field on your contact page with the value of the subject parameter (the bit after "?subject=") in the url. I'm not a PHP developer so I won't attempt to give you the code for this.

Hope this helps

Tom

EDIT: I just re-read your question and saw that the subject value is taken from the title of the current page. In which case, you don't need any javascript - just use the first method I mentioned to add the page title to the link href.

Answer (score 0):

Like tomds says: You don't need javascript, just add the page title to the href in order to pass it to the php script.  The php code to display this data is just:

```
<?php echo $_GET["subject"]; ?>
```

Just put this between the quotes in the value attribute of the input.

UPDATE:  If you don't have access to the form script, you can use jQuery or javascript to read the url 'subject' parameter, then set the form input, something like this:

```
var subj = $.url.param("subject");
$("[name=your-subject]").val(subj);
```

EDIT: You need to use the following jQuery plugin in order to get the subject parameter as shown above: https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser

But if you don't want to use that, here is a javascript function you can use instead:

```
function getQuery(key_str) {
// return value of key_str variables query string of url
// Ex: url="index.html?alert=5&page=index"; if key_str = "alert" then it returns "5"
  if(window.location.search) {
    var query = window.location.search.substr(1);
    var pairs = query.split("&");
    for(var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
      var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
      if(unescape(pair[0]) == key_str) return unescape(pair[1]);
    }
    return null;
  } 
}
```

Then do:

```
var subj = getQuery("subject");
$("[name=your-subject]").val(subj);
```

Comment: I am using the contact form 7 wordpress plugin, how can I add this snippet into that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wordpress, sorry.  But I have updated my answer with an alternative solution.